# Resizing Grid Column after any columns are collapsed

Tags: wpf

I have three buttons in a Grid.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" />
  <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B" />
  <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" />
</Grid>
```

I expect, that Buttons with Visibility="Collapsed" shall not occupy space.

For example

(1)

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" /> //33% of space
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B" /> //33% of space
<Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" /> //33% of space
```

(2)

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" /> //50% of space
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B" /> //50% of space
<Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" Visibility="Collapsed" /> //0% of space
```

(3)

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" /> //100% of space
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B" Visibility="Collapsed" /> //0% of space
<Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" Visibility="Collapsed" /> //0% of space
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Instead of changing visibility of button change width of column `<ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>`. Even unused column will take space unless with is `Auto`

Comment: In this example, it looks like you'd be better off with a StackPanel than a Grid.  Then when you collapse elements, the layout will change as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding ElementName=A,Path=Tag}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=B,Path=Tag}"  />
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding ElementName=C,Path=Tag}"  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" Name="A" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B"  Name="B"  />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" Name="C" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```